# Receiving UDP message in Python

Tags: python, udp

I am trying to get a simple Python script to receive UDP messages, and I cannot get it to work. The following code is based on other suggestions on this forum.

```
import socket

#UDP_IP_REC = "192.168.10.1"
UDP_PORT_REC = 5005

sock_rec = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                        socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

sock_rec.bind(('', UDP_PORT_REC))

while True:
    data, addr = sock_rec.recvfrom(4096) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
    print("received message: %s" % data)
```

I have the following code sending the data that I would like to receive:

```
import socket

Forces = [2.1,2.2,2.3,0.1,0.2,0.3]

UDP_IP = "192.168.10.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005
MESSAGE = b'Forces: %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f, %.2f' % (Forces[0], Forces[1], Forces[2], Forces[3], Forces[4], Forces[5])

print("UDP target IP: %s" % UDP_IP)
print("UDP target port: %s" % UDP_PORT)
print("message: %s" % MESSAGE)

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP

while True:
    sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

wait = input("Press Enter to continue.")
```

I am sending from a virtual machine to my native OS, and I can use wireshark to see the message at the receiving side. However, the recvfrom() function is not receiving anything. I am ruling out firewall issues since I can see the packets in wireshark.
Any ideas as to something seemingly so simple does not work?

Comment: Do you want to multicast by passing empty string as IP in binding?

Comment: Try changing UDP_IP in client to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1".

Comment: I was using empty string as IP to rule out as many possibly sources for the problem as possible. I tried changing to localhost, and that worked. It led me to further investigate the firewall, and it turns out Wireshark works before the firewall. So adding Python to the exception list has solved the issue. 

Thak you guys for the help.